# After replacement of RAM system won't load

Tags: hardware, hp

I have ubuntu 16.04  on HP laptop.

Recently I added 2 GB RAM.
And stuck on load.
Screen continue on loading some codes ...

> [3040.039005] Call Trace:
>   [] _raw_spin_lock+0x21x/0x30

Comment: You made sure the RAM was compatible in your system, right?  You also *tested* the RAM one stick at a time to make sure the RAM wasn't bad, right?  Laptop RAM is also far more finnicky than Desktop or Server RAM too, so you *really* need to make sure the memory is run through `memtest86`.  Also, remove the new RAM and get the old RAM back out, and make sure the system still boots on the old RAM.  If it does, chances are the RAM sticks you've got new are at fault.

Comment: Same laptops just OS different and rams for some reasone in slots 2gb and 1gb. So win laptop is unused I just took on ram to Ubuntu laptop.

Comment: On the grub menu there should be a memory test option. Run that instead of booting into Ubuntu.

Comment: I start it. And it looks take long... But for fullfil my question I leave PC over night.

Comment: You only need to run the memory test for a couple of minutes to confirm that all your RAM is readable&writable & looks to be working OK.  The rest of the testing it does is just stress testing by writing every different combination of 1s and 0s possible & reading it back, over and over again. This is useful for diagnosing much more rare & intermittent problems but not applicable in this situation.